# Do map services go stale?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, map-service

This has happened several times over:

I publish a dynamic map service, and then use the JavaScript API to allow the user to select features to obtain attribute information as well as to zoom to features using zoom buttons located on a left pane, one per feature listed. I test the map, and both functions work properly. I come back the following Monday, and while the attribute query function still works properly, when I click any one of the zoom buttons on the left pane, it fails to zoom to the feature that is listed.

Why the difference in behavior? Does the map service need to be periodically refreshed? Seems kind of silly to have to maintain a map service in such a way.

The following is the full code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  body,html,#main{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;width:100%;}
  #map{padding:0;border:solid 1px;}
</style>

<script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad:true };</script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
<script>
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");
  dojo.require("dojo.parser");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
  dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
  dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

  var map, countiesLayer;
  var identifyTask, identifyParams;

  function init() {
    //setup the popup window 
    var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({
      fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]))
    }, dojo.create("div"));

    map = new esri.Map("map",{
      basemap: "topo",
      center: [-89.211, 40],
      zoom: 7
      //infoWindow: popup
    });

    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", mapReady);

    //add the counties demographic data
    countiesLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TEA/MapServer/1",{
      mode:esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
      outFields:["County_nam","OBJECTID"]
    });

    //define a selection symbol 
    var highlightSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setColor( new dojo.Color([50,205,50,.25]));
    countiesLayer.setSelectionSymbol(highlightSymbol);

    dojo.connect(countiesLayer,'onLoad',function(layer){     
      var query = new esri.tasks.Query();    
      query.where = "1=1";
      layer.queryFeatures(query,function(featureSet){
        var items = dojo.map(featureSet.features,function(feature){
          return feature.attributes;
        });
        var data = {
          identifier:"OBJECTID",
          items:items};
        store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:data});
        grid.setStore(store);
        grid.setSortIndex(1,"true"); //sort on the county name          
      });
    });

    var landBaseLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TEA/MapServer",{opacity:.55});
landBaseLayer.on("load", function() { landBaseLayer.minScale = 0; landBaseLayer.maxScale = 0; });
    map.addLayer(landBaseLayer);

    map.addLayers([countiesLayer]);

    //modify the grid so only the COUNTY_NAME field is sortable
    grid.canSort = function(col){ if(Math.abs(col) == 2) { return true; } else { return false; } };
  }

  function mapReady(map){
   dojo.connect(map,"onClick",executeIdentifyTask);
   //create identify tasks and setup parameters 
   identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TEA/MapServer");

   identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
   identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
   identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
   identifyParams.layerIds = [0];
   identifyParams.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
   identifyParams.width  = map.width;
   identifyParams.height = map.height;
  }

  function makeZoomButton(id){
    var zBtn = "<div data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button'><img src='http://frenchinmind.com/resources/zoom-in-tool-button_318-26666.jpg'";
    zBtn = zBtn + " width='18' height='18'";
    zBtn = zBtn + " onClick=\"zoomRow('"+id+"')\"></div>";
    return zBtn;
  }

  function zoomRow(id){
    countiesLayer.clearSelection();
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.objectIds = [id];
    countiesLayer.selectFeatures(query,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW,function(features){
      //zoom to the selected feature
      var countyExtent = features[0].geometry.getExtent().expand(5.0);
      map.setExtent(countyExtent);
    });
  }

  function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
    identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

    var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);

    deferred.addCallback(function(response) {     
      // response is an array of identify result objects    
      // Let's return an array of features.
      return dojo.map(response, function(result) {
        var feature = result.feature;
        feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
        if(result.layerName === 'HighUnemploymentTracts2000wCity'){
          console.log(feature.attributes.ObjectID);
          var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "<b>Census Tract:</b> <br/> ${NAME00} <br/><br/> <b>County:</b> <br/> ${County_nam} <br/><br/> <b>Percent Unemployed:</b> <br/> ${Unemployme}");
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
        //else if (result.layerName === 'Building Footprints'){
          //var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Parcel ID: ${PARCELID}");
          //feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        //}
        return feature;
      });
    });


    // InfoWindow expects an array of features from each deferred
    // object that you pass. If the response from the task execution 
    // above is not an array of features, then you need to add a callback
    // like the one above to post-process the response and return an
    // array of features.
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([ deferred ]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
  }

  dojo.ready(init);
</script>
```

County

Comment: Services don't go stale; But Maybe your data has changed? Some other process deleted/edited the feature?

Comment: Highly doubt it. It's happened several times, and the difference in outcome was after a weekend, so the data was likely left untouched.

Comment: I'm also getting inconsistent results depending on how I'm viewing it and on which browser. I've been using Firefox, which hasn't allowed zooming at all today. When I use Chrome, most of the Zoom to Feature buttons work when I embed the script into my Wix webpage. When I try to open the html doc on either browser, only the basemap and pane is visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe clearing your browser cache? This helped with a similar situation with our Flexviewer app when we had some underlying database changes. Seems overly simplistic but it worked for our issue though i realize you have no data changes with your service as we did.

Comment: Holy crap, that worked! Thanks a lot Jaspar! I wish I could mark your comment as an accepted answer. Just to be clear, this should only be necessary for development, correct? It would be no good if users had to routinely clear their browser cache as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe clearing your browser cache? This helped with a similar situation with our Flexviewer app when we had some underlying database changes. Seems overly simplistic but it worked for our issue though i realize you have no data changes with your service as we did. Not sure about the development portion of your above comment/question but it seems like a one time fix as I've hadn't had any issues with it since I cleared my browser cache/history/cookies. Also,if you have the link in your favorites bar, it will need to be deleted and re-saved to the favorites bar.

Comment: Thanks Jaspar! I've noticed that certain features won't zoom in after the page has been open for awhile, so I periodically have to clear the browser cache to get it back to normal. Annoying, but I'll have to settle with it.